# type string is not a sub-type of type int flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating an app which fetches the data from API, initially, I can successfully able to fetch the data but after few days I am getting an error of "type string is not a subtype of type int flutter" whenever I open the app. I did not even change the code but still, it is showing an error on the screen

> PrayerRepository.dart

```
    abstract class PrayerRepository {
      Future<List<Item>> getItem();
    }
    class PrayerRepositoryImpl implements PrayerRepository {
      @override
      Future<List<Item>> getItem() async {
        var response = await http.get("https://muslimsalat.com/riyadh.json?key=key");
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var data = json.decode(response.body);
          List<Item> item = Welcome.fromJson(data).items;
          return item;
        } else {
          throw Exception();
        }
      }
    }
```

> HomePage.dart

```
    ListView.builder(
          itemCount: item == null ? 0 : item.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int pos) {

            return new Container(
              child: new Center(
                child: new Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: new Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text("Fajr"),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                                  ),
                                  Text(item[pos].fajr),
```

Comment: I didn't look at the code, but flutter currently has some upgrading issues and this might interest you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59513825/4465386

Comment: What does data at https://muslimsalat.com/riyadh.json?key=key look like?

Comment: How does `Welcome.fromJson` implemented?

Comment: @Pavel Welcome.fromJson is from Model.dart i have updated the code above hope you understand it.

Comment: It seems your edit is overwrited by another edit

Comment: Also show raw text response from https://muslimsalat.com/riyadh.json?key=key

Comment: @Pavel {"title":"","query":"riyadh","for":"daily","method":"1","prayer_method_name":"Egyptian General Authority of Survey","daylight":"0","timezone":"3","map_image":"https:\/\/maps.google.com\/maps\/api\/staticmap?center=24.711667,46.724167&sensor=false&zoom=13&size=300x300","sealevel":"622","today_weather":{"pressure":"1016","temperature":"24"},"link":"http:\/\/muslimsalat.com\/riyadh","qibla_direction":"243.92","latitude":"24.711667","longitude":"46.724167","address":"","city":"","state":"Riyadh Province","postal_code":"","country":"Saudi Arabia","country_code":"SA","items":[{"date_for}

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed your code then the API you are calling may have been changed.In such case you can check the api or change `Welcome.fromJson()` to handle the correct kind of data